# How to implement Coordinator Layout in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

Hi i am learning to use coordinate layout. I want to know how do i implement coordinator layout in a fragment. Can any one post some tutorials or example here ?

This is my activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.manish.planetdelhi.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.manish.planetdelhi.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/midu_cover"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/paralax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/detail_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The Fragment can just be the RecyclerView. I don't see the purpose of moving CoordinatorLayout to the Fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems to be fine.. But why have have you used a coordinator layout in an activity as well as in a fragment. You should only keep it in fragment and simply modify your activity xml to be-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.manish.planetdelhi.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also a good tutorial-
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

**UPDATE: BTW, just a suggestion**- it seems you are using a scrollable view(recycler view). So I suggest that you just put the recyclerview in a fragment and the rest of the code in the activity.

Your activity xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.manish.planetdelhi.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/midu_cover"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/paralax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frame"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And your fragment xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now simply inflate the frame layout at runtime.

Comment: The activity xml could just be a `fragment` tag - No need for the RelativeLayout, or the `content_main.xml`

Comment: @cricket_007 you are absolutely correct. Manish you can also do as cricket_007 suggested.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma thanks. but where will my toolbar go then ?

Comment: @ManishGupta You have already specified the toolbar in your fragment.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma
what if i have 5 fragments ? so i have to add a separate toolbar in each fragment ?

Comment: @ManishGupta. I have edited my answer. In such a case you should follow that. That is the best approach.